# JSON Containing Binary Data

Tags: php, json, uuid

I've been on working on this for ages. I am receiving a `JSON` from a request to an API and unfortunately the key's of each entry is a time uuid which is in binary format. I'm trying to use `json_decode()` to decode the json into a `PHP` array. However, when I echo the string I have about 80 entries but after the decode into the array, it trims it down to about 40 entries,

I should mention that I don't need these values that are in the keys, I could just strip them off if possible using `array_values()` maybe?

Any advice would help Thanks!

Here's some sample data

> "\u001c":{"down":"1280069835000","off":"1279893600000","on":"1279886400000","up":"1280077035000"},"=":{"down":"1280163435000","off":"1279893600000","on":"1279886400000","up":"1280167035000"}

Comment: Could we see a sample of the json in question?

Comment: Can you edit the question to insert the sample.  Its muuuccchhh more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually contacted the development team, and they converted the binary uuid to string format, and it worked like a charm. Looks like this sort of thing may not be possible besides manually parsing out the JSON. Thanks for your efforts all!